# progress dialog not working

Tags: java, android, progressdialog

I am trying to display a progress dialog in java 'A'. At the moment that am calling from 'A' a class from java 'B' which the certain java it download data from a webservice and save the data to a file. The progress dialog it does not show. The code I am using is:

```
ProgressDlg= ProgressDialog.show(Doctor.this, "","Loading. Please wait...", true);
String time_batch=mDataIntent.getExtras().getString("TIME_BATCH");
String patientid=mDataIntent.getExtras().getString("PatientId")
mGetHeartRate = new GetHeartRate(Doctor.this, mHandler);
mgetEcgAnalized = new getEcgAnalized(Doctor.this, mHandler);
mGetHeartRate.getHeart(patientid,time_batch);                                      
mgetEcgAnalized.getECG(patientid, time_batch, "I".toString());
ProgressDlg.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you executing the ProgressDialog in a AsyncTask? Something like this:

```
public class ExampleTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    private ProgressDialog progressDlg;
    private Context context;
    private Handler progressHandler;

    public ExampleTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressHandler = new Handler();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //to do
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String filePath) {
        if (progressDlg != null) {
            progressDlg.dismiss();
            progressDlg = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(final Integer... values) {
        final int progress = values[0] / 1000;
        if (progressDlg == null) {
            progressHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    final int max = values[1] / 1000;
                    progressDlg = new ProgressDialog(context);
                    progressDlg.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                    progressDlg.setMessage("Message");
                    progressDlg.setMax(max);
                    progressDlg.show();

                }
            });
        } else {
            progressDlg.setProgress(progress);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not am not using AsyncTask and i don't know how this work and how i can call it from my activity

Comment: i try it and work but now i have another question. is it possible to update the message of the progress dialog in the asyngtask?

Comment: You can set the message of the progress dialog and think that it's possible to update it but I have never done it.

Comment: on the doInBackground i have use an intent in order to request a class to run. the certain class search and connect for wifi network. on this step the bar it freeze and does not spin. what can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "", PopUpHelper.LOADING, true);
dialog.show();
```